# Template dequeue method has an undeclared identifier

Tags: c++, templates, queue

So I'm currently implementing a queue as a singly linked list. Everything is going fine, but the compiler is flagging me at my dequeue method.

This is what Visual Studio barks at me:

> error C2065: 'Removed' : undeclared identifier

Here is my dequeue method which is supposed to return the value that was just removed from the queue:

```
template <typename Type>
Type QueueLinked<Type>::deque() {
if (queueFront == 0) {
    cout << "Queue is empty! There's nothing to remove!" << endl;
} else {
    nodeType<Type> *temp;
    temp = queueFront;
    queueFront = queueFront->next;
    Type Removed = temp->dataItem;
    delete temp;

    if (queueFront == 0) {
        queueRear = 0;
    }
}
return Removed;
}
```

Here is my node struct:

```
template <typename Type>
struct nodeType {
    Type dataItem;
    nodeType<Type> *next;
};
```

This seems like an extremely simple error to have, but I'm not seeing what is causing this. Hopefully I'm not being too dumb, but it wouldn't be the first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare it in the `else` block, of course it is undeclared outside of it. Declare it before the `if`.

Try this way:

```
template <typename Type>
Type QueueLinked<Type>::deque() {
  Type Removed;
  if (queueFront == 0) {
    cout << "Queue is empty! There's nothing to remove!" << endl;
  } else {
    nodeType<Type> *temp;
    temp = queueFront;
    queueFront = queueFront->next;
    Removed = temp->dataItem;
    delete temp;

    if (queueFront == 0) {
        queueRear = 0;
    }
  }
return Removed;
}
```

Comment: You're 100% right. I should have seen that I was returning something only declared in some cases. Rookie mistake, but a lesson learned.

Comment: You might also ask yourself exactly what you *are* returning when nothing was removed!

Comment: I was immediately suspect of that fact. In my head I was justifying it as just leaving Removed undefined, but it was painfully obvious after Matzi's assistance that if it was never declared then this leads to a whole separate issue.